# How does the default webpage in IIS 7 works?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am new to web designs and i am trying to use IIS and asp along with html. I opened the IIS and noticed the default web site and manged to find the directory **C:\inetpub\wwwroot**.

In the folder is an .htm file called iistart. I created a new folder in the path **C:\inetpub\wwwroot** called test and added my own basic htm page. I then tried to run the URL **localhost/test**, but i keep getting an error message.

Error message:
Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"   and  HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Whenever i customise the iistart.htm file and run the URL it works even when i put it in the test folder under  **C:\inetpub\wwwroot**.

I feel like i am missing something, so is it something to do with my code in the file i created myself or are you just limited to using the iistart.html file?

Comment: What did you call your html file? is its name in the Default Document list in IIS Manager?

Comment: Thanks i changed the name to index.html and it worked. I previously named it asptest.html, but if there is a Default Document list can i view it?

Comment: you can add/remove default document. here's a [link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true)  to do it in iis 6

Comment: and [here's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771439(v=ws.10).aspx) for IIS 7

Comment: @th1rdey3 - the TechNet docs are ok, but the iis.net docs are better: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument